# Member reference type issue

Tags: c, linked-list

Hi everyone I'm having a problem with my code and I really don't know how to fix it.
It's telling me that member reference type 'Word'(aka 'struct dict_word *') is not a structure or a union.
I'm trying to change my struct dict_word to word as as you can see on my typedef but when I do it it's giving me that error.
Please have a look at my code I would really appreciate if you could explain that to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct dict_word *word;
typedef struct node *Node;
typedef struct double_linked_list *DLL;
struct dict_word
{
    char words[100];
    int year[10];
    char eng_synonyms[100];
    char heb_synonyms[100];
};

struct node
{
    word data;
    Node *next;
    Node *previous;
};

struct double_linked_list
{
    Node *head;
    Node *last;
};

int SpliString(struct dict_word* entry, const char *str) // Here is where I'm trying to change struct dict_node to word
{
    long sz,j,k;

    int yearIndex;
    char *buffer;
    char *endOfYears;
    char *endOfYear;
    char *endOfDefinition;
    char *endOfWord = strstr(str, "_#_");

    //Sets the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by ptr
    //to the specified value (related as an unsigned char)
    memset(entry, 0, sizeof(struct dict_word));



    if (endOfWord)
    {
        sz = endOfWord - str;

        strncpy(entry->words, str, sz);

        endOfYears = strstr(endOfWord+3, "_#_");

        if (endOfYears)
        {
            sz = endOfYears - (endOfWord+3);
            buffer = endOfWord+3;

            yearIndex = 0;
            j = 0;

            while(yearIndex<10 && buffer+j<endOfYears)
            {
                entry->year[yearIndex] = atoi(buffer+j);

                // check year for negative...
                if (entry->year[yearIndex]<=0)
                    return 0;

                // Locating substring
                endOfYear = strchr(buffer+j, '_');

                if (endOfYear)
                {
                    j = endOfYear - buffer;
                    j++;
                    yearIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            endOfDefinition = strstr(endOfYears+3, "_#_");

            if (endOfDefinition)
            {
                sz = endOfDefinition - (endOfYears+3);
                k = 0;

                for(j=0; j<sz; j++)
                {
                    if (endOfYears[j+3]==',')   //Q11: what's j+3?
                        //A11: skips _#_
                    {
                        entry->eng_synonyms[k] = ' ';
                        k++;
                    }
                    else if (endOfYears[j+3]>='a' && endOfYears[j+3]<='z')
                    {
                        entry->eng_synonyms[k] = endOfYears[j+3];
                        k++;
                    }
                    else if (endOfYears[j+3]!='_')
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }

                k = 0;
                sz = (str+strlen(str)) - (endOfDefinition+3);

                for(j=0; j<sz; j++)
                {
                    if (endOfDefinition[j+3]==',')
                    {
                        entry->heb_synonyms[k] = ' ';
                        k++;
                    }
                    else if (endOfDefinition[j+3]>='A' && endOfDefinition[j+3]<='Z')
                    {
                        entry->heb_synonyms[k] = endOfDefinition[j+3];
                        k++;
                    }
                    else if (endOfDefinition[j+3]!='_')
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            // check for legality
            for(j=0;j<(int)strlen(entry->words);j++)

            {
                if (entry->words[j]<'a' || entry->words[j]>'z')
                    return 0;
            }

            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: works for me when compiled with gcc.

Comment: What are the **exact** error message and the line on which it occurs?

Comment: Compiled with VS2010 was ok except the line where `    char *endOfWord = strstr(str, "_#_");`
"`const char*` cannot be used to init an entity of `char*`"
but structs and typedefs were ok .

Comment: What is your development environment?  I compiled and built it right away after adding `int main(void){ return 0;}` to your code, in my environment.

Comment: it says member reference type 'word'(aka 'struct dict_word *') is not a structure or a union would you like me to send you a link of my entire code?

Comment: the line on which it occurs?

Comment: exactly. when i change 'struct dict_word' to 'word' if gives me this error

Comment: Are you changing it to 'word' or 'word *' ?

Comment: i change it to -> int SpliString(word* entry, const char *str)

Comment: remove `*` from `word* entry` --> `word entry`